# Is it possible to create an aws data pipeline which can be manually trigger with parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Is it possible to create an AWS data pipeline which I can run manually and when I trigger it I wish to pass parameters to execute.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you mean when you say "run pipeline manually"?

You can activate ("trigger") the pipeline from the command line by calling **activate-pipeline** command. This command requires pipeline id and optionally accepts parameter values bag as pipeline configuration. To get more details about this command, run

> aws datapipeline activate-pipeline help

e.g.

> aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-ABCDEF1234 --parameter-values myStringValue="Hello world" myArrayValue=value1 myArrayValue=value2

or

> aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-ABCDEF1234 --parameter-values-uri s3://myBucket/withParameters/forPipeline.json

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently supported in Data Pipeline. I believe what you are looking for is **Event-Driven Scheduling** with possibility of supplying parameters to the specific run instance.

I would suggest you to explore following options:

1. Use of **Lambda** - that supports execution of arbitrary code based on triggers from S3. Then use S3 to supply either nothing or input (act as parameters) for the run instance.
2. Build your own using **AWS SWF and SQS**

There are hacks to make it work with Data Pipeline but I would suggest to take none of these and wait for Data Pipeline to support this feature.

**Hack# 1**:

You can let your pipeline run on a schedule. Your pipeline would have three components:

1. ShellCommandActivity (to run shell script with staging file from S3. Data Pipeline does staging of files from S3 to your resource)
2. S3 Precondition
3. (Optionally) Resource to run your ShellCommandActivity

Now in your shell script check for S3 file. You can have logic to either let this execution be a no-op if nothing/empty-file in S3 or read S3 file and pass them as argument to your program.

**Hack# 2**:

You can add S3 precondition (pointing to location say: s3://my-bucket/marker-file-#{scheduledStartTime}) to the activities in your pipeline, that act as your triggering mechanism. Whenever you want to make a particular interval run, then you can put the corresponding file (say s3://my-bucket/marker-file-2015-10-01:00:00:00) in S3.

This hack is so bad, I don't feel good about explaining more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Since you posted your question AWS has created a new "`scheduleType`", `ondemand`, which allows you to run a pipeline whenever you invoke "activate pipeline". Here's an example [invoking a pipeline via AWS Lambda](https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/OnDemandWithLamdaFunctions).